# Web Push PHP library Error

Tags: php, web-push

I am trying to put push messages on my website with the PHP Push Web library.

- [link to the git library](https://github.com/mksmith1a/php_push_demo)
- [Link to a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi9d6MjiBGQ)

Registration when accepting notifications works well. Save and delete if you have accepted or canceled the subscription to notifications.

The error appears when you try to send a message : First I installed GMP, it is well installed, but now it shows a different error with Vendor files.

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Mdanter\Ecc\Primitives\CurveParameters::__construct() must be an instance of GMP, resource given
    called in /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Curves/NistCurve.php on line 136 
    and defined in /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Primitives/CurveParameters.php on line 39

Call Stack:
    0.0006     238472   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/send_push_notification.php:0
    0.0118     429552   2. Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush->sendNotification() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/send_push_notification.php:55
    0.0120     435776   3. Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush->flush() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/WebPush.php:115
    0.0120     436896   4. Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush->prepare() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/WebPush.php:156
    0.0122     438872   5. Minishlink\WebPush\VAPID::getVapidHeaders() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/WebPush.php:258
    0.0136     472216   6. Mdanter\Ecc\Curves\NistCurve->generator256() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/VAPID.php:123
    0.0136     472352   7. Mdanter\Ecc\Curves\NistCurve->curve256() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Curves/NistCurve.php:149
    0.0138     477328   8. Mdanter\Ecc\Primitives\CurveParameters->__construct() /home/ubuntu/workspace/php_push_demo/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Curves/NistCurve.php:136
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using it in

Comment: I've fixed it updating PHP to 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it I had to update my PHP 7.0 to 7.1 version. After that I haven't had any more problems.

You can get more information about the library [here](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php)